# Ability to launch chrome with extensions loaded with watir-webdriver

Tags: google-chrome-extension, watir-webdriver

I'm attempting to launch chrome using watir-webdriver but with a specific extension loaded. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in ruby. When I run the following code

`@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, :switches => %w[--load-extension="file path of the extension"])`

I will get this message:[image]

Now what I noticed was odd was the dual path. I'm not sure where the first half of the path is coming from ("...Google\Chrome\Application\21..."). The 2nd half of it is what I specified in the code. When I click OK it'll launch the browser (it will wait until I do) but without the extension loaded. What's odd about the error is the manafest.json file *is*
in that folder location (and no it's not an extension issue) and looks fine to me. I can launch the browser normally (outside of the automation) and it'll run the extensions. Let me know if there's more information that you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I figured out what the problem was. I am now using this line of code:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--load-extension=.../Chrome/User\ Data/Default/Extensions/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/0.9.7_0]
```

looks like it doesn't like the quotes around the path. Took those out and it launched the extension fine.

Comment: Note: this seems to be the case with all parameterized Chrome switches for `watir-webdriver`.