# Watir Webdriver Load Chrome Extension

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir

I'm trying to load a chrome extension with Watir, and I'm having issues.
I found this related question: [Ability to launch chrome with extensions loaded with watir-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586751/ability-to-launch-chrome-with-extensions-loaded-with-watir-webdriver).  However, I am still having the same issue after following that.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'ruby-debug'
require 'nokogiri'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--load-extension=~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/anepbdekljkmmimmhbniglnnanmmkoja/0.1.12_0]

sleep(10)
browser.close
```

I also tried copying the extension from /Extensions to /Desktop and loading from there to no avail.

The error I get is `Could not load extension from ... Manifest File Missing or Unreadable.`
The Manifest file does indeed exist and seems to be a correct file in JSON format.

Trying to load different extensions fails as well.

Answer (score 2):

Download the chrome extension crx file,

```
Store the args or any other option need to pass in the watir_opts hash 
 watir_opts[:extensions] = ['path of *.crx file']
 browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: watir_opts
```

This worked for me.
Note: I didn't encode using 'base64' gem

Answer (score 0):

If you pack the extension and then base64 it, you can load it into the Chrome browser right from your ruby code.

1. Pack your extension into a *.crx file. You can follow [this](http://www.booyagadget.com/2011/05/how-to-package-your-google-chrome-extensions-and-install.html) guide, or just google how to pack a chrome extension.
2. Base64 it then add it to your desired capabilities list. You could use some code similar to this one:

   ```
      chrome_extensions = []
      chrome_extension_path = '\home\user\packed_chrome_extension.crx'
   begin
     File.open(chrome_extension_path, "rb") do |file|
       chrome_extensions << Base64.encode64(file.read.chomp)
     end
   rescue Exception => e
     raise "ERROR: Couldn't File.read or Base64.encode64 a Chrome extension: #{e.message}"
   end

   # Append the extensions to your capabilities hash
   my_capabilities.merge!({'chrome.extensions' => chrome_extensions})

   desired_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(my_capabilities)

   browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' :desired_capabilities => desired_capabilities)
   ```

And don't forget to `require 'base64'` too.

The example is for a remote web-driver instance, but I think it should work when using web-driver locally too. Just adjust the arguments passed to `Watir::Browser.new`.