# Need help to access Chrome toolbar using Watir webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have Chrome extension downloaded whose icon is in toolbar and I need to access it. I am using Chrome on Windows 7. is this possible using watir?

Comment: [watir](http://watir.com/) and [watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/) are ruby libraries for programmatic browser manipulation.  If you are looking to automate chrome with specific extensions, this might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106604/watir-webdriver-load-chrome-extension

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can automate anything in Chrome *chrome* with Watir or Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use some other UI level automation tool.  Watir and anything based on Webdriver (Selenium, watir-webdriver, capybara) can't automate things outside the browser DOM (Document Object Model).  that means the controls of the browser itself are 'off limits' to those tools

My first choice would be to look at [RAutomate](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation)  The syntax is very similar to what Watir users, so it will feel natural to you if you need to use it within your tests.

[AutoIT or XDO](http://auto.rubyforge.org/) might be another choice
[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) might be another, I mostly use it to deal with flash controls and other very difficult to automate, not 'visible' at the program level stuff.